# Linear Transformation on a basis problem

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

How would one go about solving this linear transformation? I've tried several approaches but I'm not sure which is right and I haven't seen a similar problem I can go off of.

Consider the basis $S=\{p_1,p_2,p_3\} \text{ for } \mathcal{P}_2 \text{ where }$
$$p_1(t)=t^2+t+1\\
p_2(t)=-t^2+t+1\\
p_3(t)=t^2-t+1$$

Let $p\in \mathcal{P}_2$ be defined by $p(t)=-10t^2+15t-25$.

(a) Find scalars $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in R \text{ so that }p=\alpha p_1+\beta p_2+\gamma p_3$.

(b) If $T:\mathcal{P}_2\rightarrow \mathcal{P}_1$ is the linear transformation so that
$$Tp_1(t)=3t-1\\
Tp_2(t)=2t-3\\
Tp_3(t)=2t+1$$

Find $T(p)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to go about solving this:

(a) To find $a, b,$ and $c$ so $-10t^2+15t-25=a(t^2+t+1)+b(-t^2+t+1)+c(t^2+t+1)$

$=(a-b+c)t^2+(a+b-c)t+(a+b+c)$,

solve $a-b+c=-10$, $a+b-c=15$, and $a+b+c=-25$ .

Add the first two equations to solve for $a$, subtract the first from the third to solve for $b$,

and subtract the second from the third to solve for $c$.

(b)  If $p=ap_1+bp_2+cp_3$,

then $T(p)=T(ap_1+bp_2+cp_3)=aT(p_1)+bT(p_2)+cT(p_3)$ by linearity of $T$.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by first declaring that $p(t) = ap_1(t) + bp_2(t) + cp_3(t)$ for scalars $a,b,c$.  Notice then this forms the following equations:

\begin{eqnarray*}
a-b+c & = & -10 \\
a+b-c & = & 15 \\
a+b+c & = & -25 \\
\end{eqnarray*}

or rather, as a matrix

$$
\left [ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -1 & 1  \\
1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array} \right ] \left [ \begin{array}{c}
a\\b\\c\\
\end{array} \right ] \;\; =\;\; \left [ \begin{array}{c}
-10 \\ 15 \\ -25 \\
\end{array} \right ].
$$

Solve this equation to find $a,b,c$.  Once you find these constants, then you can figure out part 2 by computing:

$$
Tp \;\; =\;\; a(Tp_1) + b(Tp_2) + c(Tp_3).
$$